# UPDATE table set date field

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to update a date field from a row but it does not seem to be affecting it but it is updating other columns as expected. I must be missing something when setting the date:

```
$task_id = $_POST['task_id']; 
$task_started_status = htmlspecialchars($_POST['task_started_status']);
$task_start_date = date('Y-m-d');


// Attempt update query execution
$sql = "UPDATE task_list 
        SET task_started_status = $task_started_status, task_start_date = $task_start_date 
        WHERE task_id='$task_id'";
if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
    header('location: ../tasks.php');
} else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($con);
}
```

The database is using the `DATE` data type but no errors occur it still believes its all valid - no errors - just not updating and if I `VAR_DUMP` on the `$task_start_date` it outputs the date id expect it to be.

Comment: What are the values of all those POST arrays/variables? If any of those are strings, you "should" be getting an error. Plus, you're taking this from a form, what does that look like?

Comment: The values are for $task_id = id of the post(INT), $task_started_status = single value of either 0,1,2,3(INT) and the date should be the DATE() as mentioned above

Comment: `task_start_date = $task_start_date` that needs to be quoted here `task_start_date = '$task_start_date'` since it's a string `Y-m-d`. what's the column's type also?

Comment: Well that fixed it - is this is because it turns into a string?

Comment: it is exactly that Dan.

Comment: Thanks man - I thought I was going crazy (been staring at this for too long clearly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I stated in comments:

`task_start_date = $task_start_date` that needs to be quoted here
`task_start_date = '$task_start_date'` since it's a string `Y-m-d`.

Plus, `Y-m-d` MySQL is interpreting that as `2016` minus `06` minus `06` (as per today's date here) and that error checking you're using, should have thrown you an error about it, but you said it didn't which I find strange.

> *but no errors occur it still believes its all valid - no errors*

When doing an UPDATE, use `mysqli_affected_rows()` for actual truthness.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

Also adding `exit;` after header. Otherwise, you code may want to continue to execute.

You could have used `CURDATE()` instead of `$task_start_date = date('Y-m-d');` being `task_start_date = CURDATE()` where no quoting would have needed to be used.

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

---

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).